# Set page of ViewSet in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have the following code:

```
class GeonamesCountryViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = GeonamesCountrySerializer
    ordering = ('country_name',)
    offset_limit = 'required'

    def get_queryset(self):
        country_geoname_ids = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('country_geoname_ids', None)
        name_prefix = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('name_prefix', None)

        if (country_geoname_ids is None) and (name_prefix is None):
            raise exceptions.ParseError("Either 'country_geoname_id' or 'name_prefix' must be defined.")

        if country_geoname_ids is not None:
            country_geoname_ids = [param.strip() for param in country_geoname_id.split(',')]
            queryset = GeonamesCountry.objects.filter(country_geoname_id__in = country_geoname_ids)

        if name_prefix is not None:
            if len(name_prefix) < 2:
                raise exceptions.ParseError("'name_prefix' must be at least 2 characters long")
            queryset = GeonamesCountry.objects.filter(country_name__istartswith = name_prefix)

        paginator = Paginator(queryset, self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('limit', 10))
        selected_page = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('page')

        try:
            countries = paginator.page(selected_page)
        except EmptyPage:
            raise exceptions.ParseError("'Page Empty")


        return queryset
```

**Is it possible to default to page one instead of `raise exceptions.ParseError("'Page Empty")` when the EmptyPage exception is thrown?**

After reading the documentation I see it is easily done when not using a ViewSet, but how can I do it from within a ViewSet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will be quite safe by doing this:

```
try:
    countries = paginator.page(selected_page)
except InvalidPage:
    countries = paginator.page(1)
```

Notice the `InvalidPage` exception, so you can cover non numbers as well.

**-- UPDATE --**

It seems like the the cleanest way would be to override pagination class, it's the only way that gives you control over returned page number:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage

class MyPaginator(Paginator):
    def validate_number(self, number):
        try:
            number = super(MyPaginator, self).validate_number(number)
        except InvalidPage:
            number = 1

        return number


class GeonamesCountryViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    paginator_class = MyPaginator
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah actually I know this however my question is how do I set the paginator on the output of the ViewSet? The ViewSet is taking care of page pagination itself so even if I use the code you put above, it will not set the page to page 1.